# Google Apps Script - Assigning Function Output to Variable and performing document.write

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

On the Index.html file, I'm trying to grab a variable from an user input form, run the input through a function that is in the Code.gs file, and then print the function result to the user.

**Index.html:**

```
 function BestWorkoutData(){
  var ExerciseVariableRaw = document.getElementById('ExerciseInput').value;
  var setsArray = google.script.run.iterateThroughRows(ExerciseVariableRaw);
  document.write(setsArray);
}
```

It's returning as undefined. I currently just have the iterateThroughRows() function returning "hello" on the CODE.gs file.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: The return from `iterateThroughRows(ExerciseVariableRaw);` will be sent to withSuccessHandler(function name or anonymous function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
google.script.run
  .iterateThroughRows(ExerciseVariableRaw)
  .withSuccessHandler(setsArray => document.write(setsArray));
```

See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication.